# Sometimes my ipad app resumes to previous state correctly, sometimes it restarts

Tags: objective-c

I developed an ipad application.
Some part of the application will bring the user out of the application, to open safari browser.

Supposedly, if the user double click the HOME button to launch the multitasking panel, and select my app again, my app SHOULD RESUME to previous state.

But I noticed that, my app is currently behaving unpredictably.

Sometimes it is able to resume to previous state.
Sometimes it restarts from the very beginning state (even if i juz left the app for less than 1 minute).

How is this behaviour designed?

P/S: Currently I didnt put any single line of code to control this behaviour.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is expected behavior.

When leaving your app it goes to background, but it may be killed by the system at *any* time. Also, some older devices don't support backgrounding at all.

You really should save all state when entering background - see the app delegate methods and notifications.

Comment: How eiko, are you sure Apple designed it such that it may be killed by the systen at ANY time? I thought there is a time out...

Comment: When in background, it will just get killed whenever the system thinks it needs more memory etc. There might be a timeout as a maximum as well - I don't know, and it doesn't matter. It's just that you can *never* be sure if switching apps will resume or restart your app.